# how to make dynamic vue tabs, loading data from api

Tags: vue.js, tabs, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm trying to make tabs, which are a list of categories from an API obtained through vuex. How do I load data of a certain category by ID in tab content when clicking on a specific tab?

```html
<ul class="tabs">
   <li class="list-group-item" v-for="(category, index) in SUB_CATS(681)" :key="category.id">
      <button class="d-block tab-btn" :class="['tab-button', { active: currentTab === index[0] }]"> 
        {{category.title}}
      </button>
   </li>
</ul>
//tabs-content

<div class="tab-content">
   <div class="tab-pane fade" 
     v-for="product in products" :key="product.id"
     :class="{ 'active show': isActive('tab-1')}">
      <div class="product-item">
        {{ product.name }}
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add ```@click``` event on button and pass the value/id you need to fetch data from api. So like this ```@click="fetchData(category.id)"``` and declare ```fetchData()``` in methods

Comment: how can i make it with vuex?
on click category changed, but data dont come from vuex

`mounted() {
        this.$store.dispatch('TAB_PRODUCTS', { cat: this.activeCategory })
        }
`
VUEX:
`async TAB_PRODUCTS({ commit }, { cat }) {
    const tabProducts = await axios("https://example.com/api/get-items.php", {
      method: "GET",
      params: {
        cat,
        token: "0e94e098eac"
      }
    })
    commit('SET_TAB_PRODUCTS', tabProducts.data)
    return tabProducts
  },
`

Comment: Are you still facing issue because I see you have accepted the answer given ?

Comment: partially works, but i still cant get data, 
I get the data in first tab, but when I click on another, I dont, I don’t know how I need to re-make the request through vuex in the api to get new data of category

Comment: Do you have any github repo or something so I can take a look at it ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the `computed` to filter the tab content:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    categories: ['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3'],
    content: [{text: 'text1', category: 'Cat1'},{text: 'text2', category: 'Cat2'},{text: 'text3', category: 'Cat3'}],
    activeCategory: 'Cat1'
  },
  computed:{
    activeContent(){
      return this.content.filter(x => x.category === this.activeCategory)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <button v-for="category in categories" :key="category" @click="activeCategory = category">{{category}}</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    {{activeContent}}
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/thesheepman/pen/BaKjrxa)